# React Router - What is the difference between Route children and component props

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got some troubles understanding what's the diferrence between this:

```
<Route path="user/:id" component={UserComponent} />
```

and this:

```
<Route path="user/:id" children={<UserComponent/>} />
```

inside `Switch` component when using React Router.

In both cases those components will render if the url will look like this "/user/4322". I'm reading React Router documentation but I can't understand this use case correctly (https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Route/route-props)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it:

https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/react-router-what-is-the-difference-between-route-children-and-component-props/429503

@DanCouper from FreeCodeCamp forum explained it perfectly:

> the first one is if you want to mount a new component when the route
> matches. This is what things most often look like: you have a set of
> routes and they all open a new “screen”, last component unmounts, new
> component mounts, everything gets blown away. It’s the simplest way to
> do things.
>
> second one is if you want something to render all the time and not
> remount. So for example, as in the example in the docs, you have a set
> of navigation links, and you want to animate between them on route
> change. If you used component this wouldn’t work, because the new
> component would mount every time and the animations wouldn’t happen.
> But because children is used, can still have the URL change in the
> browser but not have everything be blown away every time the URL
> changes.
>
> children (and render) are going to be more fiddly to use most of the
> time, because they cater to less common scenarios (in children's case,
> preventing new component creation every time routes change, allowing
> the UI to dynamically change based on route).